# Tcl 8.5 vs 8.6 script throws error when run from python

Tags: python, tcl, freebsd

My Python Script on Freebsd 9.2 is throwing error, while it worked fine on Freebsd8.2.

test.py

```
import os
import subprocess
tclsh = '/usr/local/bin/tclsh'
process = subprocess.Popen([tclsh, 'run_tests.tcl'] )
```

test.tcl

```
proc sleep {N} {
    after [expr {int($N * 1000)}]
}

puts "--- Initializing----"
```

Throws the error

```
File "run_tests.tcl", line 1
    proc sleep {N} {
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So if I change the python script

```
-tclsh1 = '/usr/local/bin/tclsh'
+tclsh1 = '/usr/local/bin/tclsh8.5'
```

It works fine on Freebsd9.2.

However, if I execute command on command line it works fine too.

```
/usr/local/bin/tclsh  test.tcl
```

Error is thrown while running the command via python script on Freebsd 9.2 with  tclsh1 = '/usr/local/bin/tclsh'

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Thant's a python syntax error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> proc sleep {n} {
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    proc sleep {n} {
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Are you sure /usr/local/bin/tclsh is a Tcl interpreter?

This line looks funny:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['tclsh1', 'test.tcl'], bufsize=1, stdout=stdout, cwd=cwd)
```

If `tclsh1` is a variable, why is it quoted?

Comment: Agreed. That's not an error coming out of Tcl, so whatever is going on, it's not what the questioner is expecting/analysing it to be.

Comment: If tclsh1 is a variable, why is it quoted?                             Sorry my bad corrected the post.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/tclsh run_tests.tcl works fine. But when it is run from subprocess.open it complains.